# Load CSV with line breaks

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am loading [this CSV][1] to Excel with VBA.
I am validating the CSV with [CSV Lint][2] and I get three errors with line breaks.

My code is:

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
        Dim fileName As String, folder As String    
        folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        fileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.csv")
    
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A6").Select
    
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
            .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName , Destination:=ActiveCell)
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
            
        End With
```

Is it possible to remove the line breaks without modifying the CSV file to a new one?
I have tried many macros but nothing seems to work.

If I have to modify the CSV to a new one I have this code:

```
Dim fso As Object, tsIn, tsOut
Dim s As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim newCSV As String
      
filePath = folder & fileName
newCSV = folder & "report.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile(newCSV, 1)



Do While tsIn.AtEndOfLine <> True
    s = tsIn.readline
    s = Replace(s, vbCrLf, "")
    tsOut.write s
Loop
tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close
    
Kill filePath
```

but it removes all the line breaks in the CSV file.

How can I search for the line breaks that affect my Excel?

Comment: `tsOut.WriteLine s`

Comment: no change.. the new CSV is identical to the old CSV

Comment: Then maybe `vbCrLf` is not the thing you want to replace in it. There is also `vbCr` and `vbLf` - Use `Instr` to figure out which one it is.

Comment: Once you figure out which one is there to be replaced, make sure you still are using `tsOut.WriteLine s`

Comment: Looking at your sample, I can only see one record that has linefeed (first one, "RSK-254093"). But since there is no indentation, how would a computer be able to tell that lines 2 and 3 should be one record, and not two (incomplete) ?  CSV is a fragile format for multiline.  Do you have the possibility to put an end-of-line marker in a final field, then run the CSV through a filter ?

Comment: This is exactly my problem.. The second and third line of the CSV should be one record.. I cant use end-of-line marker in a final field. Actually I will be using different CSV files each time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the CSV as a workbook and copy the data into your active sheet. Any quoted line breaks will appear within cells.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub loadcsv()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbCSV As Workbook, n As Long
    Dim fileName As String, folder As String
    
    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileName = Dir(folder & "*.csv")
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(folder & fileName, False, True)
    With wbCSV.Sheets(1)
        n = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        .UsedRange.Copy ws.Range("A7")
    End With
    wbCSV.Close False
    ws.Columns("A:T").AutoFit
    ws.Rows("7").Resize(n).AutoFit
    MsgBox n & " rows loaded from " & folder & fileName, vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV specification [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#RFC_4180_standard) a requirement is:

> - MS-DOS-style lines that end with (**`CR/LF`**) characters (optional for the last line).

This is confirmed for [your CSS Linter](https://csvlint.io), in it's ["How to write CSV" section](https://csvlint.io/about#how_write_csv).
(See also the "common errors" section.)

> Line endings use **`CRLF`** (Windows line endings) and the column names and fields are separated by commas.

Your code appears to be removing the [CRLF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)'s.

Your sample CSV appears to use LF's (based on me copy/pasting from your link into [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and going "*View → Show Symbol → Show All Characters*".

Therefore, I think you need to replace your `Replace` line with:

```
s = Replace(s, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I can see in Notepad++ that the report.csv file has no errors now. Unfortunately the second and third line are one record but the excel imports them as two separated lines.. I am not sure how I can avoid that